# Setting a name for a screen session

Tags: gnu-screen

Is there a way to give a particular name to a unix screen session? For instance, say I'm running the same program multiple times, each with different parameters and I want to tell which one is which.

Answer (score 181):

You can name a session when starting it with the `-S name` option. From  within a running screen, you can change it by typing

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>,<kbd>:</kbd> followed by `sessionname name`<sup>(1)</sup>.

You can view running screen sessions with `screen -ls`, and connect to one by name with

```
screen -xS name
```

<sub>(1):`name` is and an arbitrary string which will become the new session name. If the session name contains whitespace, quote it with single or double quotes.</sub>

Within a single screen session, you can also name each window. Do this by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd> then the name you want. You can view an interactive list of named windows by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>"</kbd>, and select the one you want to switch to from that list.

Naming both screens and terminals within screens is really helpful for remembering what they are and why you started them in the first place.

Comment: Renaming a screen session after it's started is possible (using `:sessionname NEWNAME`), but it's "generally discouraged". The `$STY` environment variable still refers to the original name. See the `screen` manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Session-Name.html

Comment: heads-up: you need a uppercase A,  to rename the window!

Answer (score 39):

There are two concepts here, and I'm not sure which one you have in mind:

- You can have multiple screen windows. Each window runs a shell or other program. All the windows are hosted by the same process. `C-a c` creates a window, `C-a n` and `C-a p` switch to the next/previous window, and so on.
- You can have multiple screen sessions. Each session is hosted by its own process and is independent of all other sessions. Starting screen without any reattach (`-r` or `-R`) option creates a new session.

Windows have titles, which can be set through the `-t` command line option, the `C-a A` key binding, the `title` command, or the `\ek` escape sequence. See [shellter's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12227/unix-screen-setting-name/12228#12228) for more details.

Sessions can have names. You'd typically set the name on the command line with the `-S` option; if you don't specify a name, screen makes one up. If you use multiple screen sessions, you'd typically give them different session names. You can list the running screen session with `screen -ls`; the first word on each session line is `12345.sessionname` where 12345 is the screen process ID. Use `screen -r sessionname` or `screen -r 12345` to resume a session indicated through its name or process ID.

Comment: In the default key bindings, to change title you have to use C-a A.

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer as it states the difference between session and window very clearly.

Answer (score 22):

To start:

```
screen -S mysession
```

To resume:

```
screen -r mysession
```

[Credit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202111/how-can-i-assign-a-name-for-a-screen/3309696#3309696)

Comment: This is the simpler and straightforward answer.

Answer (score 19):

Ah... Screen, it takes me back  ;-)

For one window

```
-t name
    sets the title (a.k.a.) for the default shell or specified program. 
    See also the "shelltitle" .screenrc command.
```

For multiple sessions started from your `.screenrc`

```
screen -t top 2 nice top
screen -t ....
```

Here's a link to one on-line copy of the  [man-page for screen.](http://www.slac.stanford.edu/grp/cd/soft/epics/extensions/iocConsole/screen.1.html)

As @MrFooz rightly points out, the `$0` is not expanded when inside single quotes, the correct code is,

```
cat scrnTitle.sh
#/bin/bash
echo -ne "\ek${0}\e\\"
```

As pointed out in comment below by @lindes, there is also a keyboard/interactive way to change the title: <kbd>Ctrl a</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> (Control-a followed by capital A).

---

If you're going to be using `screen`, it is really worth reading through the man page completely, as there are **lots** of features.

I still don't have a system with a working `screen` so I can't test to verify.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot. Is there anyway to rename an already existent screen session?

Comment: @Charlotte : see edits. Thanks for the votes!

Comment: Nice answer @shellter! I'm curious, did you say "takes me back" to mean you use something else these days (e.g tmux), or just that it's [over 32 years old](http://www.softpanorama.org/Utilities/Screen/history.shtml)?

Comment: @tutuDajuju : Gulp, now that I think about it, I've used `screen` at least 25 years. Takes me back, because now it is a special use case that would take me to `screen`. Normally I just keep opening `X-Terms`, but I remember when it seemed impossible to run `X` on a 486 PC ;-) Cheers!

Comment: @shellter FYI, I ran X on a 486 PC with 8Mb RAM back in 1992...

Comment: @Eno : Oh well, I recall 1MB 486 PC being  a big thing! ;-/ Glad someone got it to work ;-)

Comment: @shellter I used the first Linux distribution - SLS - which came on 30 floppies :-) I setup a dual-boot with an 80Mb partition for Linux (including 10Mb swap :-)

Comment: That's some heavy lifting. I didn't really get to use an *nix until my job where I started on Sun 3 hardware. Wow, 30 floppies, that takes some determination. I thought Windows on 8 floppies was bad ;-! Ciao for niao!

Comment: Nit: double quotes are needed instead of single quotes so that the `${0}` substitution occurs: `echo -ne "\ek${0}\e\\"`.

Comment: Yeah, very good. Updated and thanks!

Comment: Ooh, the "\ek[...]\e\\" thing is new to me; cool!  That said, two suggestions to make this answer better (though it still has my upvote): (1) Add a mention of <kbd>C-a</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> as an interactive way to do the same thing; (2) when editing your answer, just edit it to correct it, removing the bad information, instead of leaving bad information in and adding good information after it.

Comment: @lindes : Hmm, your comment just showed up in my in-box (today-ish). Yes, you're right on both accounts, I will update my answer with your improvments. Thanks. I used the `<kbd>C-a` often as a user, but I don't think I ever realized/needed to change the title. Good to know that is possible! Cheers!

Comment: @shellter: cool.  And given the round trip delays in comments, I figured I'd go ahead and just do an edit to help things be even better.  It needs to be approved first, but hopefully you'll see it.  In the mean time, typing `<kbd>C-a</kbd>` (without any backticks, though I'm typing it within them in this comment), should get you what you want (and is what I did in my edit).  If I remember correctly, it doesn't work in comments?  Here's attempting it anyway: <kbd>C-a</kbd>

Answer (score 6):

While running `screen`:

`Ctrl+a` (or whatever your `screen` escape sequence is) `A`

Answer (score 5):

The answers above already tell you how to name a screen when you start it. They also point out that a screen can't be renamed after it has been started. The window title can be set but the name used to attach to the screen remains pid.pty.host.

However, to achieve a useful effect I've found that using alias work pretty well. If I forget to name a screen or find myself in a session with a bunch of screens up that have naturally become screens for particular tasks I simply set an alias for the command to attach to them.

example:

```
alias goncompile='screen -r 2354'
```

Issuing the alias command by itself will remind you what screens you have up and command you have set to attach to them.

Use `unalias` to remove them.